# Change an item property received from a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, properties

I need to change the value of an item of a list returned by a query... It must be simple, but i can´t see it using linq.

The list is composed by elements of this structure:

```
public struct HeaderButton
    {
        public string content {get; set;}
        public BitmapImage icon {get; set;}
        public PageContainerFactory.ContainerType containerType {get; set;}
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

private List<HeaderButton> _headerButtons;
public List<HeaderButton> HeaderButtons
    {
        get
        {
            if (_headerButtons == null)
                _headerButtons = new List<HeaderButton>();
            return _headerButtons;
        }
        set { _headerButtons = value; }
    }
```

I´ve tried this:

```
HeaderButtons.First(x => x.containerType == CurrentContainer.CType).IsSelected = true;
```

And the compiler tells me:

*Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Linq.Enumerable.First(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' because it is not a variable*

And now the query that i´m trying:

```
var h = HeaderButtons.First(x => x.containerType == CurrentContainer.CType);
h.IsSelected = true;
```

I had to take the element in a var because of the compiler error. And doing it as represented in the code above, obviously "h" does not points to the "HeaderButtons" real element since it is a new HeaderButton object and not a reference.

Comment: what is the source for `_headerButtons`?

Comment: h is a HeaderButton, and h is the object in the List HeaderButtons (same reference)

Comment: `HeaderButtons.First(x => x.containerType == CurrentContainer.CType).IsSelected = true` should work fine

Comment: Why is `HeaderButton` a struct? Seems like it should be a class and if it was then your code would work fine. This kind of issue is the reason people suggest it is bad practice to create mutable structs.

Comment: HeaderButton is a struct because it is only used inside a class and i didn´t think that it would be useful to take it out and make a class of it.

Comment: Then that would explain the issue you are having. Structs are value types, and as such are supposed to exhibit the behavior described. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) for some guidelines on when to use struct/class

Comment: Please put the solution as an answer not as an edit, and accept it. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comments, i decided to make a nested class in place of the structure since this kind of objects are not used outside of the content class, and now that is a class (object reference) and not a struct (value), everything works fine.

The code:

```
sealed class MainViewModel : ViewModelNavigator
{

    internal class HeaderButton
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage Icon { get; set; }
        public PageContainerFactory.ContainerType ContainerType { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

...

```
private List<HeaderButton> _headerButtons;
public List<HeaderButton> HeaderButtons
    {
        get
        {
            if (_headerButtons == null)
                _headerButtons = new List<HeaderButton>();
            return _headerButtons;
        }
        set { _headerButtons = value; }
    }
```

...

```
HeaderButtons.First(x => x.ContainerType == CurrentContainer.CType).IsSelected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is saving you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Because HeaderButton is a struct it is passed by value instead of by reference. Which means that the Linq First operator is acting on (and will return) a value copy of the element in the list.

Because the return value from First is not assigned to anything it is temporary  and will go out of scope at the end of the statement, and what's more since it is a value copy and not a reference to the item in the list any changes you make to it will not affect the item in the list anyway.

If this were to compile you might easily be misled to thinking that you had updated the item in the list, which you would not have. By refusing to compile the compiler is saving you from having to track down what could be a tricky bug to find.

If you have reason to keep HeaderButton as a struct then a statement like this will enable you to update it.

```
var hb = HeaderButtons.First(x => x.containerType == CurrentContainer.CType);
HeaderButtons[HeaderButtons.IndexOf(hb)].IsSelected = true;
```

If you go this route you need to ensure your struct's equality operations behave in a way that is useful to you, which hinges on the same factors as 'If you have reason to keep HeaderButton as a struct' because part of wanting to use a struct instead of a class means wanting value equality instead of reference equality semantics.